# How to store a sequence of integers in a C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Assume I have to store 100 integers in array, should I declare an array and store all 100 integers from 1 to 100 or is there any solution that will work better ? and loop them through a for loop or any loop concept in c++

example

```
   int numbers [100] = { 1 ,2 3,......10};
for(){
//manipulate the array elements here
}
```

or

```
int numbers = {100};
```

what if I have more than 100 elements ? i.e. integer number from 1 to 200 or more  what is good concept to achieve ?

Comment: `int numbers = {100};` initializes _one_ `int` to `100`.  _"what if I have more than 100 elements ?"_ - well, do you know at compile time if that's the case? If not, you want a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: You are a bit too abstract. Where do the numbers come from? If it is just a sequence `1, 2, 3, 4`, etc,, you might not have to store them anywhere (because you know the values anyway), but perhaps only have one variable and increment it.

Comment: @ 
BoP    a sequence of numbers from 1 to 100 like this int numbers[100] = { 1 ,2,3,........100} is this a good idea or is there any good suggestion?

Comment: If you just need one number at a time use one `int` an increment it whenever you need the next number. Creating 100 `ints` for this is just a waste of memory. What do you need those numbers for?

Comment: Is of use: [How to initialize static array from std::integer_sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658819/how-to-initialize-static-array-from-stdinteger-sequence)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) to generate a sequence.

For example, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec(100);
    std::iota(begin(vec), end(vec), 1);
    for (auto i : vec)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

If you *have* to use a raw array, you can fill it like this:

```
int vec[100];
std::iota(vec, vec + 100, 1);
```

Comment: from this piece of code you've posted is it easy to loop in reverse ? backward looping from 100 to 1                
int numbers[100];
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    numbers[i-1] = i; //or adjust your loop to start at 0 and assign i+1, etc.

Comment: @JustinWilliam • if you need to fill it with some calculated value, you can use a for-loop and calculate the value for the cell in whatever manner is appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: Or even better use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view , no need to even create the vector in memory.